# making the position of a popconfirm static

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using a popconfirm to show up when trying to close a modal, I want the popconfirm position to be below the X button of the modal, I have tried to move its position with the "overlaystyle" property and if I edit the values while the popconfirm is open it works, but if the screen dimensions change or the popconfirm is closed.

it returns to its original position, is there any way to make it stay below the X of the modal?

```
import { ExclamationCircleFilled } from "@ant-design/icons";
import { Popconfirm } from "antd";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


type EditModalCloseType = {
    width: number
    popupOpen: boolean;
    onConfirm: () => void;
    onCancel: () => void;

};


export const EditModalClose = ({width, popupOpen, onConfirm, onCancel }: EditModalCloseType) => {
    useEffect(() => {
        calculateOverlayStyle(width);
    }, [width]);
    const description = "¿Estás seguro de salir sin actualizar? los cambios se perderan"
    
    const calculateOverlayStyle = (width: number) => {
        setOverlayStyle({
            ...(width < 688 && { marginLeft: '20px', marginTop: '-160px' }),
            ...(width < 1300 && { position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%' }),
            ...(width >= 1300 && { position: 'absolute', top: '50%', left: '50%' })
        });
    }
    const [overlayStyle, setOverlayStyle] = useState({});

    


    return <Popconfirm
        title={description}
        open={popupOpen}
        placement="bottom"
        autoAdjustOverflow={true}
        overlayStyle={overlayStyle}
        icon={<ExclamationCircleFilled style={{ color: 'red' }} />}
        okText="Salir"
        okButtonProps={{ style: { backgroundColor: 'red', color: 'white' } }}
        onConfirm={onConfirm}
        cancelText="Regresar"
        onCancel={onCancel}

    />

}
```

```
const PopupCancel = () => {
    setPopupOpen(false);
  };
  const PopupConfirm = () => {
    resetFields();
    setPopupOpen(false);
    setOpenModal(false);

  }
```

I tried to create a function according to the width of the screen that would adjust it according to that property but the same error I mentioned in the post keeps occurring.

Comment: Try `align` props to set the position of `Popconfirm`. `e.g. align={{ offset: [10, 10] }`